# Charting software that represents relationships

Tags: project-management, data-visualization, charts, uml

I'm looking for a software where I can create a chart showing all companies under (and above) a holding company, including shareholders. I'm talking at least 30 companies, 20 shareholders, and relationships going in each direction.

I've tried to use mind mapping tools and other charting software to do this, but I thought there has to be a better way.

Essentially, what I'm looking for is some sort of UML for companies.

What I'm trying to do is show each company and shareholder as an entity in the chart, and have arrows representing ownerships between the companies. Ideally, I'm looking for the following features:

- Supports many-to-many relationships.
- I can set the percentage on the relationship.
- I can manipulate the chart to show only relationships related to a single entity.
- I can move and design the chart as I wish. (fonts, colors, etc.)
- I can export the chart into a pdf.
- I can import data into it somehow.

Can you guys think of anything that might fit the bill?

FWIW, I am a fairly competent programmer (as long as no one sees my code), so I'd be open to using software libraries or something.

Comment: Graphviz is your friend...

Comment: @DeerHunter Thanks for that! I was thinking of something similar! I wish it had more options though. Things like controlling the shape of the vertex and adding more info per vertex would be extremely useful for my purposes.

Comment: Graphviz has more versatility than it looks at 1st sight. Custom-shape vertices are there... Another great program is MS Visio.

Comment: If you are tracking relationships you can try Maltego/Casefile by Paterva.